# Sublime text won't open on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sublime-text

I am attempting to run sublime text on my ubuntu terminal on Windows 10. I successfully downloaded according to the instructions here (https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html). When I run commands such as `subl --help`, I see the expected list of commands.

However, when I look to open a file with `subl filename.py`, I receive no error message but nothing happens. I have looked around online and have not seen this problem come up. I am not sure why this is happening but would appreciate any help.

Comment: It's normal. WSL is not for graphic applications.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a X server on the Windows side to be able to use GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

My X server of choice for Windows is Xming, you can find it online, or you can use Chocolatey if you have it on your machine: `choco install xming`

After that, append the following line to your `~/.bashrc` in WSL: `export DISPLAY=:0`

Then start Xming by launching XLaunch either from the command line or Start Menu, go with the default settings. Restart your WSL session and when you launch GUI apps it should work.

Do note that you may need to install additional libraries pertaining to X11 on the Linux side of things.